# C# Source Generator not running

Tags: c#, code-generation, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I want to create an incremental source generator that reads a json file and creates some classes out of it. Unfortunately, when I build my solution, no files are generated. Even the debugger statement in the source generator is not hit.

I created a new project to hold my source generators:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>true</EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>
    <IsRoslynComponent>true</IsRoslynComponent>
    <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
    <CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>Generated</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="4.5.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

My existing project that holds my app references it with:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SourceGenerators\SourceGenerators.csproj"
      OutputItemType="Analyzer"
      ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

My generator code looks like this:

```
[Generator]
    public class MetricsSourceGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator
    {
        public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext initContext)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

            var textFile = initContext.AdditionalTextsProvider.Where(file => file.Path.Contains("Potato"));

            var contentProvider = textFile.Select((text, cancellationToken) => text.GetText(cancellationToken).ToString());

            initContext.RegisterSourceOutput(contentProvider, (sourceProductionContext, fileContents) =>
            {
                var metricDefinitions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MetricDefinitions>(fileContents);

                foreach (var metric in metricDefinitions.Metrics)
                {
                    var source = GenerateClassSourceCode(metric);

                    sourceProductionContext.AddSource(metric.Name + "AnalyticsCounter.cs", SourceText.From(source, Encoding.UTF8));
                }
            });
        }

        private string GenerateClassSourceCode(MetricDefinition metric)
        {
            var className = metric.Name + "AnalyticsCounter";

            var dimensionsOwnParameters = string.Join(", ", metric.Dimensions.Select(dimensionName => $"string {dimensionName}"));

            var dimensionsTrackValueParameters = string.Join(", ", metric.Dimensions);

            return $@"
// <auto-generated/>
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;

/*
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This class is auto-generated by {this.GetType().Name}.
Please DO NOT modify it manually!
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
*/
namespace App.DataLayer.Analytics.Metrics
{{
    public class {className} : AnalyticsCounter
    {{
        public {className}(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
            : base(""{metric.Name}"", telemetryClient)
        {{
        }}

        public void Increment({dimensionsOwnParameters})
        {{
            Metric.TrackValue(1, {dimensionsTrackValueParameters});
        }}
    }}
}}
";
        }
    }

    public class MetricDefinitions
    {
        public MetricDefinition[] Metrics { get; set; }
    }

    public class MetricDefinition
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool IsSimpleCounter { get; set; }

        public string[] Dimensions { get; set; }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I supposed to build it in a different way?

Comment: Debugging generators is difficult, breakpoint doesn't just work, you need `if (!Debugger.IsAttached) Debugger.Launch();`

Comment: I don't understand why you have used IIncrementalGenerator?
Can't it just a simple function which returns string ? Can you  try by removeing generator attribute and interface. So that you can debug atleat.

Comment: @VishalPawar I'm using a generator because that's how you programmatically autogenerate files in a C# solution.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Even if I throw an exception inside of my generator, it doesn't have any effect. It's like the code isn't being executed at all.

Comment: [The cookbook](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#additional-file-transformation) seems to suggest that it must be an "additional file" (see  properties - Build Action)

Answer (score -1):

You are almost there...

Your target project needs to have something like the following in the .csproj file to locate the "potato" files that you want the source generator to process.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="file1.txt" />  <!-- logging will be controlled by default, or global value -->
</ItemGroup>
```

The "Include" attribute can be for a specific file or you can use globbing patterns to match multiple files.

More information can be found at this link (my apologies in advance if github removes or changes it).:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#additional-file-transformation

Your source generator .csproj file does not need these two entries:

```
<EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
<CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>Generated</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
```

These two lines, if you need them, need to go in the target .csproj file.

You may also run into some problems getting Newtonsoft.Json nuget package to work in your source generator.  See the following link for more info, in particular for Pain Point 3: Transient Dependencies (again, sorry if the link is broken):

https://turnerj.com/blog/the-pain-points-of-csharp-source-generators

Other than these suggestions, your code looks pretty solid.  Good luck.